# Which pretrained model will be best for my dataset?

Tags: machine-learning, neural-networks, computer-vision, image-processing, python

I am trying to build a classification algorithm having 28 classes. These classes consists of **Logo** of companies like adidas , Nike etc. I have very low dataset below than 100 images and greater than 70 images. I have trained CNN model but not got decent results . Accuracy is not good. I want to switch on pretrained model. I don't know which pretrained model should I use either VGG , ResNet etc. because I saw on Internet that you may use Pretrained model on  similar dataset but I have logo of companies , I don't know that any pre trained model is trained on such similar type of objects or not. How should I choose pre trained model that will performs well on my dataset.

Comment: We can't really know - as is typical with these type of things, you probably just have to give it a try and see for yourself.

Comment: @Juho Any Guess ?

Comment: No way to know without trying it.

Answer (score 2):

There's no general answer.  In this field, you'll just have to try multiple approaches and see how well they work.  We usually won't know what will work best until we try it.

I can suggest three candidate approaches:

1. Get more data.
2. Use a pre-trained model and fine-tune it.  You can use any state-of-the-art model, pick a version that was pre-trained on ImageNet, and then fine-tune it (either fixing the first n-1 layers and training only the last layer; or training all layers, but with a smaller step size).
3. Use few-shot learning.  This will probably require more sophisticated methods and more study.

Aggressive data augmentation might be useful.

Comment: When I increase the number of Convolutional layers , accuracy goes upward with 2 percent. I have increased up to 4 Hidden layers and got an accuracy of 45% max . What is your perception , should I increase more ?

Comment: @Hamza, sorry, this site isn't a good fit for what you seem to be looking for.  The site is not built for interactive back-and-forth interactions.